# Gradle custom task only applied to certain subprojects?

Tags: configuration, build, gradle, subproject

I have created a custom `herpderp` Gradle task:

```
task herpderp(type: HerpDerpTask)

class HerpDerpTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def herpderp() {
        println "Herp derp!"
    }
}
```

With this, I can add this task to other Gradle builds an use it inside build invocations for other projects:

```
gradle clean build herpderp
```

Now, I have the following multi-project setup:

```
myapp/
    myapp-client/
        build.gradle
        src/** (omitted for brevity)
    myapp-shared/
        build.gradle
        src/** (omitted for brevity)
    myapp-server
        build.gradle
        src/** (omitted for brevity)
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

Where `myapp/build.gradle` is:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile (
            'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7'
        )
    }
}
```

And where `myapp/settings.gradle` is:

```
include ':myapp-shared'
include ':myapp-client'
include ':myapp-server'
```

I would like to be able to navigate to the parent `myapp` directory, and run `gradler clean build herpderp` and have the `herpderp` task only run on the `myapp-client` and `myapp-shared` projects (not the server project).

So it sounds like I need either another custom task or some type of closure/method inside `myapp/build.gradle` that:

1. Runs `clean build`; then
2. Drops (`cd`) into `myapp-client` and runs `herpderp`; and then
3. Drop into `myapp-shared` and runs `herpderp`.

What do I need to add to *any* of my files in order to get `herpderp` invoked from the parent build command, but only executed in the client and shared subprojects?

Comment: You can run `herpderp` task in a given module with: `gradle :myapp-shared:herpderp`

Comment: Thanks @Opal - so are you saying something like `gradle clean build :myapp-client:herpderp :myapp-shared:herpderp`? If so, is there something I could do to *wrap* that (its a bit nasty looking) so that I could have a simplified build invocation? Perhaps a way to wrap `herpderp` so that `gradle clean build smartHerpDerp` is the same as `gradle clean build :myapp-client:herpderp :myapp-shared:herpderp`. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that is what is thinking about. What you can also do is to add `herpderp` to the specified subprojects only. Will try to do it in a moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following piece of code can do the trick (should be placed in `myapp/build.gradle`):

```
allprojects.findAll { it.name in ['myapp-client', 'myapp-shared'] }. each { p ->
   configure(p) {
      task herpderp(type: HerpDerpTask)
   }
}

class HerpDerpTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def herpderp() {
        println "Herp derp from ${project.name}!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Opal (I'd upvote you if I had the rep to do so)! But what would my build invocation be inside the parent `myapp` directory? Just **`gradle clean build`**? Thanks again!

Comment: In `myapp` directory just run `gradle clean build herpderp` then `clean` and `build` will be invoked in all projects and `herpderp` only in the specified (`shared` and `client`).

Comment: You don't have to answer this @Opal (I already accepted your answer - and thanks again!) but I'm just curious as to what is happening here. If I run `gradle clean build herpderp`, how does Gradle know to execute your `findAll` closure and *only* configure `HerpDerpTask` for the selected subprojects?

Comment: It requires longer explanation: let's continue in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/67808/question-27679044?tab=general

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like I don't have enough rep to join a chat room (SO claims the minimum is 20).

Comment: You've joined the room but probably you can't talk. Ok. All the scripts are evaluated before tasks are run (I mean build along with settings scripts). When `findAll` all is executed projects are already evaluated and one can pick (via name here) required projects. `configure` comes from Project class (see gradle API) and enables configuring particular project. That's all and it's very general :/

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sub:project_filtering), you can filter subprojects and configure them this way:

```
configure(subprojects.findAll { it.name.endsWith("server") }) {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib'
    jib {
       from {
          image = 'openjdk:alpine'
       }
    }
    ...
}
```